# am trying to use $match and $lookup in my nodejs backend project to first find a request with the request id then to lookup the requested product

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

am trying to use $match and $lookup to find a request from requests collection and to retrieve the requested product from products collection using the product_id that is found in the requests
here is my db
requests db

```
[
    {
        "product_id": [
            "5f72e43125f77741e0eb8e47"
        ],
        "response": false,
        "issued": false,
        "received": false,
        "_id": "5f7323bcfc3bd333b433bf23",
        "user_id": "5f7acb75972aba55b479ce67",
        "amount": 30,
        "date": "2020-09-29T12:08:28.095Z",
        "__v": 0
    },
    {
        "product_id": [
            "5f72e46d25f77741e0eb8e48"
        ],
        "response": false,
        "issued": false,
        "received": false,
        "_id": "5f73281ffe17322548e7b009",
        "user_id": "5f7ace3c1d0f7540b054d287",
        "amount": 40,
        "date": "2020-09-29T12:27:11.035Z",
        "__v": 0
    }
]
```

and my products db looks like this

```
[
    {
        "_id": "5f72e43125f77741e0eb8e47",
        "name": "Sutures",
        "cost": 586,
        "quantity": 50,
        "category": "Specialist Items",
        "unit": "Dozen"
    },
    {
        "_id": "5f72e46d25f77741e0eb8e48",
        "name": "Vitrectomy tubing",
        "cost": 950,
        "quantity": 80,
        "category": "Specialist Items",
        "unit": "Dozen"
    },
    {
        "_id": "5f72e4a625f77741e0eb8e49",
        "name": "Laser",
        "cost": 320,
        "quantity": 24,
        "category": "Bulb",
        "unit": "Dozen"
    },
    {
        "_id": "5f72e9e514f0b816608d4c55",
        "name": "Lensometers",
        "cost": 340,
        "quantity": 12,
        "category": "Bulb",
        "unit": "Dozen"
    },
    {
        "_id": "5f730dc3309a0f3b64608f9b",
        "name": "Slit Lamp",
        "cost": 340,
        "quantity": 11,
        "category": "Bulb",
        "unit": "Dozen"
    }
```

and my code looks like this

```
router.get('/:requestId', (req, res) => {
    Request.aggregate([
        {$match: { _id: req.params.requestId}},
        {
            $lookup: {
                from: "products", 
                localField: "product_id",
                foreignField: "_id",
                as: "product"
            }
        }, {
            $unwind: {
                path: "$product",
                preserveNullAndEmptyArrays: true
            }
        }  
    ],(error, data) => {
        if (error) { res.status(500).json('No Product')}
        else{
            res.json(data)
            console.log(data)
        }
    })
})
```

but the result am getting is and empty array
[]
am not sure where I went wrong Please help out here

Comment: Its working check in [playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/w7yCoWug1Kj), might be the problem with object, you can confirm `product_id` and `_id` both should object id or should string, otherwise it will not work.

Comment: @turivishal thank you for trying it, both are object id and I try `JSON.stringify` and it's still not giving me any thing

Comment: But you have to pass this this id as object id too, its `{$match: { _id: mongoose.Types.ObjectId(req.params.requestId) }}`

Comment: I try that too and it gives me `Error: Argument passed in must be a single String of 12 bytes or a string of 24 hex characters`

Comment: you have to debug your problem, because its a kind of silly mistakes, just console that request param field and check its correct or not, then next.

Comment: @turivishal thank you for your help, it works when i tried this `{$match: { _id: mongoose.Types.ObjectId(req.params.requestId) }}'  again I don't know why it didn't work the first time you told me to try that but it does now thanks

Comment: Okay good, you can delete this question if you want, because its just you missed type casting.